# select all including null and not null values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, null

In my project I have few tables. I have a table named `e_state` having 3 columns named `State_id` `country id` `state_name`. And I have another table where I got user inputs let say it is `usr` table. User will input a **state id** which I need to compare with my  `e_state` table. Once it gets matched then from `e_state` table I will get the state name.

Now what happened I got records those didn't have any state id that means few users forgot to give the state id. now when I am fetching the records those users data are not showing.

Now I need to fetch all the data who gave their state id or forgot to
give.
So can anyone please help me out of this

So what I did
my code is

```
SELECT 
    usr.USER_ID,
    usr.USER_FNAME,
    usr.USER_LNAME,
    usr.STATE_ID,
    usr.CITY_ID,
    state.STATE_NAME,
    cty.CITY_NAME,
    rct.API_REQUEST_DATE_TIME,
    rct.API_RESPONSE_DATE_TIME,
    DATE(rct.API_REQUEST_DATE_TIME) AS API_REQUEST_DATE,
    TIME(rct.API_REQUEST_DATE_TIME) AS API_REQUEST_TIME,
    DATE(rct.API_RESPONSE_DATE_TIME) AS API_RESPONSE_DATE,
    TIME(rct.API_RESPONSE_DATE_TIME) AS API_RESPONSE_TIME,
    rct.API_OPERATOR,
    rct.API_OPERATOR_ID,
    rct.TRANSACTION_ID,
    rct.DEVICE_NUMBER,
    rct.RECHARGE_AMOUNT,
    rct.RC_STATUS_CODE,
    rct.RECHARGE_TYPE,
    rct.API_TRANSACTION_ID,
    rct.REFUND_STATUS,
    uth.PAYMENT_MODE 
FROM
    e_user_trans_hist uth,
    e_rc_transaction rct,
    e_user usr,
    e_state state,
    e_city cty
WHERE
    rct.USER_ID = usr.USER_ID
        AND usr.STATE_ID = state.STATE_ID 
        AND usr.CITY_ID = cty.CITY_ID
        AND uth.TRANSACTION_ID = rct.TRANSACTION_ID
        AND rct.RECHARGE_TYPE = 'MOBILE' 
ORDER BY  rct.API_RESPONSE_DATE_TIME DESC;
```

Comment: Why are you choosing to use archaic syntax rather than proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Because much of the Web and Oracle continue to teach it :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to JOIN the tables?

Comment: why did you tag both MySQL and SQL Server? Tag the one you're using.

Comment: @NavikGoswami - `,` is a `CROSS JOIN` and the join predicates are in the `WHERE` clause.  It's syntax that predates `JOIN`, which was introduced in `ANSI-92` *(So, only 28 years ago...)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, using `JOIN` syntax helps improve a lot of problems straight away.

```
FROM
  e_user_trans_hist uth
INNER JOIN
  e_rc_transaction rct
    ON uth.TRANSACTION_ID = rct.TRANSACTION_ID
INNER JOIN
  e_user usr
    ON rct.USER_ID = usr.USER_ID
INNER JOIN
  e_state state
    ON usr.STATE_ID = state.STATE_ID 
INNER JOIN
  e_city cty
    ON usr.CITY_ID = cty.CITY_ID
WHERE
  rct.RECHARGE_TYPE = 'MOBILE' 
ORDER BY
  rct.API_RESPONSE_DATE_TIME DESC
```

Next all you need to do is change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` where you know there can be NULLs involves *(no record to join on to)*

```
FROM
  e_user_trans_hist uth
INNER JOIN
  e_rc_transaction rct
    ON uth.TRANSACTION_ID = rct.TRANSACTION_ID
INNER JOIN
  e_user usr
    ON rct.USER_ID = usr.USER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  e_state state
    ON usr.STATE_ID = state.STATE_ID 
INNER JOIN -- Possibly here too?
  e_city cty
    ON usr.CITY_ID = cty.CITY_ID
WHERE
  rct.RECHARGE_TYPE = 'MOBILE' 
ORDER BY
  rct.API_RESPONSE_DATE_TIME DESC
```

Comment: Yes, I tried It and it worked for me. I had to change the last Inner Join to Left Outer Join as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you are joining user table first and then state table. But you should join state table first and then user table.

Thanks for reading the answer

Comment: The order your write the joins in SQL doesn't dictate the order they're joined in the execution plan. This answer is misleading.